# Same query on local/live site, vastly different performance

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, mariadb

My slow query log is showing 5,6+ second runs randomly of a seemingly normal query. Running the same query on my local clone of the site gives a 0.05s query run time. Here is the EXPLAIN of both:

[image]

I'm a bit dense when it comes to MySQL optimization but, I don't understand how this can give such different results? The tables are roughly the same, the live site is more updated but otherwise very similar.

---

**Edit:**

Instead of comparing to my local installation, I instead am comparing to my "old" live server. I just moved servers this morning.

**The OLD server DDL of the table:**

```
CREATE TABLE `wp_bp_activity` (
 `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `user_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
 `component` varchar(75) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `type` varchar(75) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `action` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `content` longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `primary_link` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `item_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
 `secondary_item_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
 `date_recorded` datetime NOT NULL,
 `hide_sitewide` tinyint(1) DEFAULT 0,
 `mptt_left` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
 `mptt_right` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
 `is_spam` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 KEY `date_recorded` (`date_recorded`),
 KEY `user_id` (`user_id`),
 KEY `item_id` (`item_id`),
 KEY `secondary_item_id` (`secondary_item_id`),
 KEY `component` (`component`),
 KEY `type` (`type`),
 KEY `mptt_left` (`mptt_left`),
 KEY `mptt_right` (`mptt_right`),
 KEY `hide_sitewide` (`hide_sitewide`),
 KEY `is_spam` (`is_spam`),
 FULLTEXT KEY `content` (`content`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1060622 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

**The NEW server DDL:**

```
CREATE TABLE `wp_bp_activity` (
 `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `user_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
 `component` varchar(75) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `type` varchar(75) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `action` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `content` longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `primary_link` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `item_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
 `secondary_item_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
 `date_recorded` datetime NOT NULL,
 `hide_sitewide` tinyint(1) DEFAULT 0,
 `mptt_left` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
 `mptt_right` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
 `is_spam` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 KEY `date_recorded` (`date_recorded`),
 KEY `user_id` (`user_id`),
 KEY `item_id` (`item_id`),
 KEY `secondary_item_id` (`secondary_item_id`),
 KEY `component` (`component`),
 KEY `type` (`type`),
 KEY `mptt_left` (`mptt_left`),
 KEY `mptt_right` (`mptt_right`),
 KEY `hide_sitewide` (`hide_sitewide`),
 KEY `is_spam` (`is_spam`),
 FULLTEXT KEY `content` (`content`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1060840 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

They are the same, but as you can see at the bottom of each the number of rows (by the AUTO_INCREMENT). They are very similar. As I said this OLD server was active this morning, so there are many recent datetimes here as well.

Running the query pictured above on both servers however, results in the same difference in "EXPLAIN" output, the NEW server is examining an insane amount of rows in 10x the time.

Comment: I am looking at your screenshot and two things jump out at me: 1) one query returns 32 rows vs 200K rows 2) one query uses where vs intersect - without further details it's hard to know where the discrepancy in performance is but I would start looking at (2) first since this obviously points at two different queries being used (which might explain the differences)

Comment: @blurfus thats what i noticed too but, as you can see in the sql text right above, it's the same exact query?

Comment: My bad, they seem the same but there could be other factors (indexing, volume of read/writes, transactions come to mind) - it's hard to tell from just looking at a screenshot

Comment: My best guess is that there are Vastly different numbers of rows in each environment. Particularly, Live has Many more dates. This matters because of the Order By, especially if the underlying table isn't indexed by date. Please, therefore, edit the question to provide two things; the DDL for creating the table (on both environments, incase they're different) and a description of the differences in the profile of the data (how many rows, across how many dates, how many have is_spam or different types, etc, etc).

Comment: I reread what you've written, that the local is a "clone" of live.so broadly similar row counts. Perhaps different indexes exist, so the full DDL on each is important. Also, depending on how you cloned live, you may have "cleaned up" the storage and effective defragmented it. Check the following for crude fragmentation estimates in mysql : https://serverfault.com/questions/202000/how-to-find-and-fix-fragmented-mysql-tables

Comment: @MatBailie just added it to the post, instead of using the local clone i'm now testing on a much, much more recently live version of the site - which is performing better, so, still unsure what this is - why is one "index" and other "index_merge" for example

Comment: Also possible is out of date (stale) table stats. Try running ANALYZE on the poorly performing table, or read here for more comprehensive options... https://www.percona.com/blog/2017/09/11/updating-innodb-table-statistics-manually/

Comment: Hm, tried, just said "OK". Ran the query again, now its 7 seconds lol. Ran again on old server, 0.0002 seconds

Comment: Did you look into fragmentation as per one of my comments?

Comment: I have to go, I'd also suggest asking here: https://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: `0.0002 seconds` -- sounds like the Query cache was on.  Run `SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE ...` to get a fair timing.

Comment: Dup of https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/289384/moved-site-to-new-similar-server-same-query-is-taking-10x-longer

Answer (score 0):

Use a "composite" index (in this order):

```
INDEX(is_spam, hide_sitewide, type)
```

Tip: When `EXPLAIN` says "Intersect", you need a composite index.

Get rid of `a.type NOT IN ...` since that test is already handled by `a.type IN ...`

Get rid of `DISTINCT`, it may be causing an extra pass to de-dup.

Use `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON SELECT ...` to get more detailed info.

Use text, *not images*, in this forum.

There may be a difference in version between the two servers -- and this may explain the different optimization technique used (or mis-used).

Comment: Unfortunately that's what I'm trying to avoid. The query is from a WP plugin, I have no control over it unless I go an manually edit the files. Which I'd be fine with if I didn't have years upon years and numerous server-transitions of these same queries...performing correctly. The only difference is MariaDB 10.5.8 on the old, and 10.5.9 on the new server.

Comment: Adding the index is independent of WP and its plugins.  WP and its plugins fail to do simple optimizations like the index I propose.

Comment: Okay...so, I added that composite index and it worked. But in a weird way. Firstly, I had to add the columns in the order you specified which is interesting. But more interesting is now, EXPLAIN is telling me of the "possible keys", this newly-created composite index is one of them ... but it doesn't use it as the actual key, now it's using "date_recorded" like it should have from the start. If I remove the composite index, it stops using date_recorded and goes back to an index_merge. Kinda odd, but it fixes the issue. I may have to add a few of these composite indexes for the range of queries

Comment: @FTLRalph - Yep, that's interesting.  If `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON...` did not help, the "optimizer trace" might.

Comment: It might evaluate both indices and find the compound one heavier to use and so chooses the date_recorded one?

Comment: @shrm - I have seen cases where the table had both `INDEX(a)` and `INDEX(a,b)`, but the Optimizer picked the smaller one when the larger would be better.  The workaround is to drop the smaller.